# react using a dynamic import name and path

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use a dynamic path for my image source. I had imported some of the images that have the same name for import and path.

```
// the import and the file name are the same
import book from "../types/book.png"; 
import table from "../types/table.png";
import chair from "../types/chair.png";
...
<div className="lc-type-wrapper">
          {TypeData.map((type, index) => {
// type value is also the same with both import name and file name
            return (
              <div className={`lc-type ${type}`} key={index}>
// it will be using in the src
                <img src="" alt={type} />
                {type}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
```

Is there a method to achieve that?

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear. Please clarify it.

Comment: @MohammadAbdulAlim I'm showing a list of data that coming from TypeData, one of the data is "chair" and I want to show a picture that has the same name as the data which is "chair". So I want to do it dynamically to set the same name for the import name and the path of the file without writing one by one.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can use `require` method to dynamically import images like this:

```
<div className="lc-type-wrapper">
      {TypeData.map((type, index) => {
        return (
          <div className={`lc-type ${type}`} key={index}>
            <img src={require(`../types/${type}.png`)} alt={type} />
            {type}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```